# else string matching in expect

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I want to use expect for telnet
after sending a command 
it may return different results
let me say, like the following 3 possibilities

```
1 successful
2 normal
3 there are something wrong...blabla
  you can refer to ....blabla


expect{
   "successful" {}
   "normal" {} 
   #here, for the third possibility, I want to use something like "else", so what should I put here? thanks!
}
```

Comment: No reason to close this valid Expect question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is `default`.

```
expect{
   "successful" {}
   "normal" {} 
   default {}
}
```